# How to find stale days in a stock price time series by using Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

Database Table

```
Date    Close price
01/01/2015  100
02/01/2015  100.2
03/01/2015  100.2
04/01/2015  100.2
05/01/2015  100.3
06/01/2015  100.2
07/01/2015  100.3
08/01/2015  100.1
09/01/2015  100
10/01/2015  99.98
11/01/2015  100
12/01/2015  100.1
13/01/2015  100.2
14/01/2015  100.2
15/01/2015  100.3
16/01/2015  100.2
17/01/2015  100.2
18/01/2015  100.2
19/01/2015  100.2
20/01/2015  100.3
21/01/2015  100.3
22/01/2015  100.3
23/01/2015  100.3
24/01/2015  100.3
25/01/2015  100.3
26/01/2015  100.2
27/01/2015  100.1
28/01/2015  100.1
29/01/2015  100.1
30/01/2015  100.1
31/01/2015  100.1
```

Expected result via oracle sql query

```
Date    Close price Stale Days count
01/01/2015  100 0
02/01/2015  100.2   0
03/01/2015  100.2   1
04/01/2015  100.2   2
05/01/2015  100.3   0
06/01/2015  100.2   0
07/01/2015  100.3   0
08/01/2015  100.1   0
09/01/2015  100 0
10/01/2015  99.98   0
11/01/2015  100 0
12/01/2015  100.1   0
13/01/2015  100.2   0
14/01/2015  100.2   1
15/01/2015  100.3   0
16/01/2015  100.2   0
17/01/2015  100.2   1
18/01/2015  100.2   2
19/01/2015  100.2   3
20/01/2015  100.3   0
21/01/2015  100.3   1
22/01/2015  100.3   2
23/01/2015  100.3   3
24/01/2015  100.3   4
25/01/2015  100.3   5
26/01/2015  100.2   0
27/01/2015  100.1   1
28/01/2015  100.1   2
29/01/2015  100.1   3
30/01/2015  100.1   4
31/01/2015  100.1   5
```

In a stock price time series if close price of the stock continues to be the same on the following days then count of stale days of the stock price keep on increasing.

Can someone have good suggestion to calculate stale days of the stock price within oracle sql without using any other programming language and it should be optimized one?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  Look at oracle analytic window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT "Date",
       Close_price,
       CASE DIFF_CLOSE_PRICE
       WHEN 1 THEN 0
       ELSE rn - LAG( CASE WHEN DIFF_CLOSE_PRICE = 1 THEN RN END ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY "Date" ) END AS Stale_Days_Count
FROM   (
  SELECT "Date",
         Close_price,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Close_price ORDER BY "Date" ) AS rn,
         CASE LAG( Close_price ) OVER ( ORDER BY "Date" )
         WHEN NULL        THEN 1
         WHEN Close_price THEN NULL
                          ELSE 1 END AS diff_close_price
  FROM   Stock_prices
);
```

**Results**:

```
Date      CLOSE_PRICE STALE_DAYS_COUNT
--------- ----------- ----------------
01-JAN-15         100                0 
02-JAN-15       100.2                0 
03-JAN-15       100.2                1 
04-JAN-15       100.2                2 
05-JAN-15       100.3                0 
06-JAN-15       100.2                0 
07-JAN-15       100.3                0 
08-JAN-15       100.1                0 
09-JAN-15         100                0 
10-JAN-15       99.98                0 
11-JAN-15         100                0 
12-JAN-15       100.1                0 
13-JAN-15       100.2                0 
14-JAN-15       100.2                1 
15-JAN-15       100.3                0 
16-JAN-15       100.2                0 
17-JAN-15       100.2                1 
18-JAN-15       100.2                2 
19-JAN-15       100.2                3 
20-JAN-15       100.3                0 
21-JAN-15       100.3                1 
22-JAN-15       100.3                2 
23-JAN-15       100.3                3 
24-JAN-15       100.3                4 
25-JAN-15       100.3                5 
26-JAN-15       100.2                0 
27-JAN-15       100.1                0 
28-JAN-15       100.1                1 
29-JAN-15       100.1                2 
30-JAN-15       100.1                3 
31-JAN-15       100.1                4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot MT0. very useful.

Comment: If this has answered your question then you can mark the answer as accepted to indicate to other users that the question is closed.